# Mixed datatypes in a column: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, dataframe, types, dtype

I am trying convert the column the column named 'service_id' to an integer type. However, the column as a string with value like 1_spl. There are many such unique strings in addition to this. I want to group them all (i.e. all strings) to one category and name it lets say "4". Given that all other values in'service_id' are of integer type. I could convert the entire column to integer type.

```
service_id  value
1_spl       23
2           45
2           2
3           39
3           13
2_spl       16
3_spl       47
3           15
2           9
```

What I have tried?

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter = "\t",dtype={'service_id':np.int64})

df['service_id'].astype(str).astype(int)

df['service_id']=df['service_id'].astype(int)
```

Gives error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.to_numeric` and pass `errors` as `coerce`, it will convert all non-numeric values to `NaN`, then you can use `.loc` and `isna()` to change these `NaN` values to whatever you want.

```py
df['converted'] = pd.to_numeric(df['service_id'], errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['converted'].isna(), 'converted'] = 4
df
  service_id  value  converted
0      1_spl     23        4.0
1          2     45        2.0
2          2      2        2.0
3          3     39        3.0
4          3     13        3.0
5      2_spl     16        4.0
6      3_spl     47        4.0
7          3     15        3.0
8          2      9        2.0
```

Additionally, you can type cast the new column `converted` to integer if you want to.